# Convert DateTime with milliseconds to SQL DateTime

Tags: .net, sql, datetime

I'm making a query like this :

```
@" if (" + logic + @") 
begin
    INSERT INTO [FRIIB].[dbo].[Incidents]
        ([RecTime]
        ,[Name]
        ,[Message])
    VALUES
        ('"     + dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + //ODBC : Canonical DT Format
```

and got SQL like this :

```
if (( 1 = 1 )) 
begin
INSERT INTO [FRIIB].[dbo].[Incidents]
([RecTime],[Name],[Message])
VALUES 
('2011.02.14 04:30:10.020',
```

and error like this :

**can't convert varchar to datetime**

How can I fix it ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Documentation about this is here: [Supported String Literal Formats for datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

So you could use ISO8601 (example: 2004-05-23T14:25:10.487), because, as stated in the doc:

> The advantage in using the ISO 8601
>   format is that it is an international
>   standard with unambiguous
>   specification. Also, this format is
>   not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or
>   SET LANGUAGE setting.

Comment: How can I convert DateTime to 2004-05-23T14:25:10.487 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you do something like this..

```
  java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

  java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dt.getDate());
```

and pass this sqlDate as a paremeter..